# Каким образом отобразить данные в barplot по строкам?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

У меня есть датасет с следующим содержимым:

> numeric_1 | numeric_2 | ... | numeric_n

Всего в данном датафрейме две строчки, я бы хотел нарисовать barplot, так чтобы высота столба зависела от значения. То есть по х у меня колонки, а по y высота столба по значению, дублируется по строчкам, то есть рядом стоящие столбца это разные строки датафрейма, примерно как в примере.

[image]

Примерно таким же образом. как это сделано на картинке.

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Делаете два subplot‘а для каждой строки и всё...

Comment: Не надо субплоты, просто два бар-графика с заданной шириной и зависящей от нее абсциссой. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/units/bar_unit_demo.html

Comment: @strawdog, хммм, а как нарисовать два графика на одной картинке без subplot’о-в?

Comment: @MaxU насколько я понял _написанное_ в вопросе, речь идет просто о мультибаре, а не о двух графиках. Картинка не совсем релевантна вопросу. Датасет один, строк - две.

Comment: @strawdog, я так понял, что картинка "символизирует" разные графики для двух строк...

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, в seaborn все как раз проще будет - не надо специально преобразовывать данные - он делает это сам при помощи параметра `hue`

Comment: Так, а как мне в seaborn сделать так, чтобы barplot в качестве х брал колонки, а в качестве y брал значение по данной колонке? hue то оно понятно.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных;)